# Making Struts2 work with normal / hand-written HTML forms

Tags: java, struts2

Is it possible to make Struts 2 work with existing forms which have already been written, but which aren't using Struts 2 to generate the forms (e.g by using `<s:textbox>, <s:radio>` etc).

Primarily, I'm only interested in the validation and handling of these forms. The forms are already being rendered and displayed as needed. I just need to be able to get the values in the backend, validate them, and process them. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes this is possible. With what exactly you are having problems?

Comment: @AleksandrM I remember that you have to use things like `<s:action>` to generate the proper url to the action, and in the action, unless you had `<s:textbox>` etc, you would not be able to receive or validate the form fields.

Comment: @ClickUpvote: You can do that, since Struts2 form tags will eventually will be converted in to equivalent HTML tags.Struts2 tag just provide more power to manipulate values from Valustack.Just submit you form and make sure have proper getter and setter in your action class and you are all set to go.

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi Would you be able to show me a very simple demo / code for a html form that submits one or two fields, and the corresponding code in struts for receiving those 2 fields? I'll be happy to award a bounty if you can

Comment: See my answer for this

Comment: @ClickUpvote You don't need to use the Struts tags, you absolutely can use your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how we can use simple HTML tags to submit values to Struts2 action.

### JSP

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="field1" value=""/>
  <input type="text" name="field2" value=""/>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

### Action

```
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport{

 private String field1;
 private String field2;
 public String getField1()
    {
        return field1;
    }

    public void setField1( String field1 )
    {
        this.field1 = field1;
    }

    public String getField2()
    {
        return field2;
    }

    public void setField2( String field2 )
    {
        this.field2 = field2;
    }

    public String execute(){
       System.out.println("******************************************** "+field1);
       System.out.println("******************************************** "+field2);
       return true;
    }

}
```

You will be able to receive values in your action class and free to use any logic you want, only drawback of this approach is that you will not be able to make direct  use of some features being provided by Struts2 tags but there are other ways to do that.

Hope this will help you

Comment: thanks.. one thing. what if instead of putting the `getFirst()` and `getLast()` methods in the action, I want to instead put them in the model itself, any ideas how I would accomplish that?

Comment: I mean if I have a `public User user` in my action, and `User` is a model class, which has functions like `getLast(), getFirst()`, etc. In this case, if I provide field names like `user.first`, `user.last` in my html, will these get assigned to the `user` model?

Comment: I did a test, and indeed, if I provide `user.first` as the field name in the html, then it does set its value onto the user model's first name field. perfect!

Comment: sorry i missed you first comment, Struts2 will take care of setting values in your model object and you are all fine to go, also there is `ModelDriven` interceptor which will put your model on top of stack and in that case you even need not to use `user` just field name is fine but i will not suggest that approach and it have few known issues

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Do you know of any interceptor which will remove the need to have public `get / set` methods, instead it can set the property directly on object?

Comment: E.g if I have `user.first` field in my html, I could have a `public User user` in my action (instead of `private` with get/set), and in User I would have `public String first, public String last` instead of getters / setters for first / last, and the interceptor would still set them up correctly?

Comment: @ClickUpvote:have a look http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/model-driven.html

Comment: That's nice, but is there any interceptor which can set the properties directly on the model without having to provide get/set methods for every field?

Comment: whcih version are you using? there is no direct way, either you need to make you properties public (no getter and setter) or have getter and setter for them, in any case i will follow getter/setter and that is a standard convention for java beans

Comment: I'm using latest version (2.x.x). I can make the properties public, i find it cumbersome and it makes my classes too long to add the get/set methods. How can I set them directly without get/set if I make them public, do i have to write my own interceptor for that?

Comment: no you do not have to add any interceptor, default interceptor stack will do  work for you, but i will suggest you to go with conventions and it will help you in future.IDE will generate fields for you with no efforts

Comment: that doesn't seem to work, if I put `user` as public and remove the getters/setters, then when i submit the form, i get a null pointer exception for it when i try to access it.

Comment: I am not talking about bean, but fields inside the bean.

Comment: I see. Its interesting, if I add the `getUser()` method back to the action, then it works even if inside the `User` class there are no getters/setters. But then why doesn't it work the same way for the action without the need for `getUser`?